# In my django HTML template my text is repeated because of {% for city in cities %} loop

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

My text in my HTML is repeated because of the {% for %} loop. I already tried to move {% if %} outside of {% for %}. Then my disappears.

This is my html template

```
{% for city in cities %}
  {% if city.author.access_challenge %}
    <p class="small text-center"> In order to get information about this  contact us through almaz@protonmail.com </p>
  {% else %}
    <table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:address' city.pk %}">{{ city.city }}</a></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my views.py

```
def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')

    context = {
        'cities':cities,
        'country':country
    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

Also I tried to change my views.py like this:

```
def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    ci = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')
    cit = list(ci)
    for city in cit:
        for cities in cit:
            context = {
                'cities':cities,
                'country':country
            }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

But when I used the for loop, I get an error that Post is not iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

my views.py now:

```
def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')
    author = Post.objects.get(id=pk).author

    context = {
        'cities':cities,
        'country':country,
        'author':author,

    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

my views.py used to be:

```
def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')

    context = {
        'cities':cities,
        'country':country
    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

Before with same code my HTML had error. But now it's working without any errors:

```
  {% if author.access_challenge %}

    <p class="text-center col-sm-12"> In order to get info about this country contact <strong>emeupci@protonmail.com</strong></p>

    {% else %}

    {% for city in cities %}
    <table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:address' city.pk %}">{{ city.city }}</a></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `forloop.first` in your code. For e.g. :

**Input:**

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% if forloop.first == True %}
        First time through!
    {% else %}
        Not the first time.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output:**

```
First time through!
Not the first time.
Not the first time.
```

For your case:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {% if city.author.access_challenge and forloop.first == True %}  
        <p class="small text-center"> In order to get information about this  contact us through almaz@protonmail.com </p>
    {% else %}
        <table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:address' city.pk %}">{{ city.city }}</a></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It didn't work. As I add `and forloop.first == true` the names of cities show up instead of `In order to get information about this  contact us through almaz@protonmail.com`

Comment: How do you exactly want your output to be? @Almaz

Comment: If city.author.access_challenge = true. I want to show only `In order to get information about this contact email` text. 
esle I want  to show the table.

Comment: try `and forloop.first == True`, I believe I've mistaken in `T` @Almaz

Comment: It kind of worked. But name of one city appeared. :)

Comment: This `forloop.first` is `True` just for the first occurrence of the loop. I think there's something wrong in your city objects.

Comment: Here is my github repo https://github.com/ualmaz/loop_problem.git

if you can help I will buy a coffee or beer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')
```

What you are tryting to get is list of all distinct cities, but what you get is a queryset of Post objects.

To get list of all distinct cities from you Post model, do:

```
Post.objects.all().values_list('city').distinct()
```

Comment: When I do that I get error `Reverse for 'address' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts\\/cabinet\\/address\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Comment: That error is related to urls and not Model query. Can you show the whole error, then maybe I will be able to help you

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /accounts/cabinet/cities/9/

Reverse for 'address' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts\\/cabinet\\/address\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/cabinet/cities/9/
Django Version:  2.1.7
Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  

Reverse for 'address' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts\\/cabinet\\/address\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

`

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the query I provided, it says django was not able to find correct url, and indeed the url you tried: `/accounts/cabinet/cities/9/` is different from what you have provided in the code: `'accounts\\/cabinet\\/address\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$'`

Comment: I will send you github repo in a minute

Comment: Okay, also tell the exact url you are trying to access

Comment: I am not trying to access any url. I just want to get rid of repeated text in my HTML. But as soon as I add `.values_list('city')` I get that url error.

Comment: Here is the github repo https://github.com/ualmaz/loop_problem.git

If you will be able to solve give me your PayPal email. I want to buy a coffee or beer :)

Comment: could you do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your virtual environment and share the text file generated

Comment: I updated my repo. Now you can find requirements.txt